# .Net Graphics.DrawString non-letter characters

Tags: .net, graphics

I am experiencing an issue where the string drawn on an image is putting non-letter characters in the wrong place, i.e. "Hello World!" draws on a jpg "!Hello World".

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One of the last parameters to DrawString is a StringFormat object, make sure you don't have the FormatFlags property of that object set to display right to left.